# Creating a function in Python for creating buckets from pandas dataframe values based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, apply, bucket

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250949/applying-multiple-conditions-for-multiple-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-efficientl) and it helped me, but now my task is more complex.

**My dataframe has ~100 columns and values with 14 scales.**

```
{'Diseasetype': {0: 'Oncology',
 1: 'Oncology',
 2: 'Oncology',
 3: 'Nononcology',
 4: 'Nononcology',
 5: 'Nononcology'},
'Procedures1': {0: 100, 1: 300, 2: 500, 3: 200, 4: 400, 5: 1000},
'Procedures2': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 10},
'Procedures100': {0: 1000, 1: 3000, 2: 5000, 3: 2000, 4: 4000, 5: 10000}}
```

I want to convert each value in each column of the dataframe into a bucket value.

My current solution is:

```
def encoding(col, labels):
    return np.select([col<200, col.between(200,500), col.between(500,1000), col>1000], labels, 0)

onc_labels = [1,2,3,4]
nonc_labels = [11,22,33,44]
msk = df['Therapy_area'] == 'Oncology'

df[cols] = pd.concat((df.loc[msk, cols].apply(encoding, args=(onc_labels,)), df.loc[msk, cols].apply(encoding, args=(nonc_labels,)))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It works well, **if all columns of the dataframe has the same scale, but they do not. Remember, I have 14 different scales.**

I would like to update the code above (or get another solution), which would allow me to bucket data. **I cannot use the same range of values for bucketing everything.**

My logic is the following:

If `Disease` == `Oncology` and `Procedures1` on this scale, convert values to these buckets (1, 2, 3)

If `Disease` == `Oncology` and `Procedures2` on this scale, convert values to these buckets (1, 2, 3)

If `Disease` != `Oncology` and `Procedures77` on this scale, convert values to these buckets (4, 5, 6)

Example of a scale and buckets:

Procedures1 for Oncology: < 200 = 1, 200-400 = 2, >400 = 3

Procedures2 for Oncology: < 2 = 1, 2-4 = 2, >4 = 3

Procedures3 for Oncology: < 2000 = 1, 2000-4000 = 2, >4000 = 3

Procedures1 for nonOncology: < 200 = 4, 200-400 = 5, >400 = 6

Procedures2 for nonOncology: < 2 = 4, 2-4 = 5, >4 = 6

Procedures3 for nonOncology: < 2000 = 4, 2000-4000 = 5, >4000 = 6

Expected output (happy to provide more info!)

```
Diseasetype Procedures1 Procedures2 Procedures100
Oncology        1             1           1
Oncology        2             2           2
Oncology        3             3           3
Nononcology     4             4           4
Nononcology     5             5           5
Nononcology     6             6           6
```

[Link with rules:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrqvlqySh_r8dRVfQVrwvPeIgF2mg5fr/view)

Comment: All scales are the same for Oncology and nonOncology, they just depend on Procedure?

Comment: Except if you have a mathematical relation, I think you have to create a file with all combinations

Comment: @Corralien, scales are different for Oncology and Non-Oncology. That is why I liked the first simple solution. It create a list of columns and tell which scale to apply for this Procedure. So with some manual tuning I would be able to apply different scales. Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: I can create some simple template. I have 14 scales for Oncology and 10 scales for Non-Oncology to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an helper file with all scales (source at the end of answer):

[image: scales]

Use `melt` to flatten your dataframe then filter out your rows with `query` and finally use `pivot` to reshape your dataframe. You can execute each line independently to show the transformations:

```
scales = pd.read_csv('scales.csv').fillna({'Start': -np.inf, 'End': np.inf})
out = (
  df.melt('Diseasetype', var_name='Procedure', ignore_index=False).reset_index()
    .merge(scales, on=['Diseasetype', 'Procedure'], how='left')
    .query("value.between(Start, End)")
    .pivot_table('Label', ['index', 'Diseasetype'], 'Procedure').astype(int)
    .droplevel(0).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Diseasetype  Procedures1  Procedures100  Procedures2
0     Oncology            1              1            1
1     Oncology            2              2            2
2     Oncology            3              3            3
3  Nononcology            4              4            4
4  Nononcology            5              5            5
5  Nononcology            6              6            6
```

Content of `scales.csv`:

```
Diseasetype,Procedure,Start,End,Label
Oncology,Procedures1,,200,1
Oncology,Procedures1,200,400,2
Oncology,Procedures1,400,,3
Oncology,Procedures2,,2,1
Oncology,Procedures2,2,4,2
Oncology,Procedures2,4,,3
Oncology,Procedures100,,2000,1
Oncology,Procedures100,2000,4000,2
Oncology,Procedures100,4000,,3
Nononcology,Procedures1,,200,4
Nononcology,Procedures1,200,400,5
Nononcology,Procedures1,400,,6
Nononcology,Procedures2,,2,4
Nononcology,Procedures2,2,4,5
Nononcology,Procedures2,4,,6
Nononcology,Procedures100,,2000,4
Nononcology,Procedures100,2000,4000,5
Nononcology,Procedures100,4000,,6
```

Comment: Here, I don't search any magical solution to your problem but think about standardize values between 0 and 1. Use probably: `pd.cut`, `np.quantile` or `np.linspace` to set labels.

Comment: thanks for putting so much time! I attached a sample file. Can you please look at it?

Comment: Do you want to keep your file format?

Comment: if possible, I would greatly appreciate it. I store data like this, it would help me a lot!

Comment: You store the data and ranges in the same file?

Comment: No. I recreated the structure of the table + gave example of ranges. Ranges can be different, I gave an example. If you can put something `in range(a, b)`, where I can change the input of the range manually, would be fantastic.